# Render child component via React-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I've been struggling with this code. I have a component which accepts a child as a prop, and it is supposed to be the base of all the pages I host.

Base.jsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Base = ({ child }) => (
    <div>
        <div className="top-bar">
            <div className="top-bar-left">
                <NavLink to="/">React App</NavLink>
            </div>

            <div className="top-bar-right">
                <Link to="/login">Log in</Link>
            </div>

        </div>

        {child.render()} // HERE IS THE CHILD TO RENDER

    </div>
);

Base.propTypes = {
    child: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
export default Base;
```

Then, in app.jsx, where lies the `ReactDom.render()`, I have this :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginPag from './components/LoginPag.jsx';
import Base from './components/Base.jsx';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage.jsx';

// for MaterialUI to work properly
injectTapEventPlugin();

const TestLogin = (props) => {
    return (<Base child={LoginPag} />);
};

const TestBase = (props) => {
    return(<Base child={HomePage}/>)
};

ReactDom.render((<BrowserRouter><MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <div>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={TestBase} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={TestLogin}/>
    </Switch>
    </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
</BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

Finally, HomePage and LoginPag look alike and here's the HomePage.jsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardTitle } from 'material-ui/Card';

const HomePage = {
    render() {
        return (<Card className="container">
            <CardTitle title="React Application" subtitle="This is the home page." />
        </Card>);
    }
};

export default HomePage;
```

My question now is : Isn't it possible to get rid of these abstractions `TestLogin` and `TestBase` ?

My final goal is to have something like this :

`<Route exact path="/" component={Base(HomePage)} />`, that is to say getting rid of the abstraction layer and directly render this in one line.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Thanks to anuragasaurus, I could achieve what I wanted. Can I do it with a class as well ? The class is declared as `class LoginPage extends React.Component` and has a `render()` method.

Comment: Well if I deleted it's only because I was angry. You can't say "Good attitude" to someone like you'd say "Good boy" to a dog. And if I didn't posted a minimal code example that's because I'm at work and I only took this java class to work on it during lunch time. But I understood the lesson though and I'll spend the rest of the week not sleeping but coding instead. Also I'll make sure not to post silly questions anymore.

Comment: Nobody said silly. Thing is: in order to help you debug problems you have to provide reasonable input. Zillions of people get down votes on questions. Happens Happens all the time. Just telld you to improve the input. I had to delete various of my own  questions over time too. Don't take this personal please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `render` to display your component inline,

```
<Route exact path="/" render={()=><Base child={HomePage} />} />
<Route exact path="/login" render={()=><Base child={LoginPage} />}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try this Asap !

Comment: That was it ! Could you tell me how can I achieve this with a class instead of a simple object ? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

With a simple object AND a class:

```
const Base = ({ child }) => (
    <div>
        <div className="top-bar">
            <div className="top-bar-left">
                <NavLink to="/">React App</NavLink>
            </div>

            <div className="top-bar-right">
                <Link to="/login">Log in</Link>
            </div>

        </div>

        {child}

    </div>
);
```

And

```
const TestLogin = (props) => {
    return (<Base child={<LoginPage/>} />);
};

const TestBase = (props) => {
    return(<Base child={<HomePage}/>/>)
};
```

To answer for the entire question :

```
<Route exact path="/" render={()=><Base child={<HomePage/>} />} />
<Route exact path="/login" render={()=><Base child={<LoginPage/>} />}/>
```